# Script to move object to world origin without changing z-axis position

Tags: python, scripting

I have a blender file with 4 objects. Every object has position `[0,0,0]`, rotation `[0º,0º,0º]` and scale `[1,1,1]` but they are located in different positions in relation to the world origin - `[0,0,0]`

I need to move them all to the world origin **except the z-axis**.

I have a script that I use to rotate all the objects in the scene but I can't figure it out how what to do in this case.

```
# rotate objects:
sel_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selectable_objects if obj.type == 'MESH']
for obj in sel_objs:
    obj.rotation_euler = (0, radians(-90), radians(270))
```

I'm using Blender 2.83.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost the original locations of the objects so technically they *are* at the origin. In the script below I've cheated and used bpy.ops to reset the objects origins to Center of Mass.

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in D.objects:
    obj.select_set(True)
    C.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    ### Pick one ###
    #bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')
    #bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='MEDIAN')
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
    obj.location[0] = 0 # x
    obj.location[1] = 0 # y
    
    C.view_layer.objects.active=None
    obj.select_set(False)
```

After batFINGER's suggestion I modified the code to not loop through bpy.ops calls. I also changed it to only affect selected objects. The original version would have moved cameras, lights and whatever else.

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

### Pick one ###
#bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='MEDIAN')
#bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')

for obj in  C.selected_objects:
    obj.location[0] = 0 # x
    obj.location[1] = 0 # y
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. Now that I saw your answer I noticed one detail that I missed. In the blend file I have "perfect" cubes but in fact it was a bad example because what I have is not a perfect square in the z-axis. What I mean is that from top view all my 4 objects are a rectangle or square but in the z-axis it's not. I attached a screenshoot to show better what I mean.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, I attached a new blend file. If you choose the top view you can see that all 4 objects are square (they also can be rectangles from top) but because they are not uniform in the z-axis, when I use your script I don't get the objects centered in the x and y axis. What I need is to ignore the z-axis completely when I define the center of mass. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: I left the other two options for setting the origin in the code commented out, but the script doesn't move the Z axis at all. The numbers get set but that isn't a big deal, you can always 'Apply Location'

Comment: @zephirus Suggest also adding a screen shot example  as to how it is now and expected result,  Ron, running the origin change operator once (outside loop)  on all selected objects will be a lot quicker when object count is high..

Comment: I know that the z-axis isn't changed. But in the x and y, the objects are not centered. That is what I need. I explained myself wrong in my question.

Comment: This is the best you're going to get programatically, I think. When you apply location you lose all the information about where the object center was.

Comment: @batFINGER good point, I modified my answer to only hit bpy.ops once and not play selection games.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I think this will work.